# Find all string parts starting with [ and ends with ] in long string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, algorithm

I have an interesting problem for which I want to find a best solution I have tried my best with regex . What I want is to find all the `col_x` values from this string using C# using regular expression or any other method.

```
[col_5] is a central heating boiler manufacturer produce boilers under [col_6]
 brand name . Your selected [col_7] model name is a [col_6] [col_15] boiler.   
[col_6] [col_15] boiler [col_7] model [col_10] came in production untill 
[col_11].  [col_6] model product index number is [col_1] given by SEDBUK 
'Seasonal Efficiency of a Domestic Boiler in the UK'. [col_6] model have 
qualifier [col_8] and GCN  [col_9] 'Boiler Gas Council No'. [col_7] model 
source of heat for a boiler combustion is a [col_12].
```

The output expected is an array

```
var data =["col_5","col_10","etc..."]
```

**Edit**

my attempt :

```
string text = "[col_1]cc[col_2]asdfsd[col_3]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"[[^@]*]");
var uniques = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList().Distinct();

    foreach(string m in uniques)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m);

    }
```

but no success.

Comment: you should probably try the problem first before asking on SO then post your attempts.

Comment: Are you looking for the actually word [Col x] or are you trying to find the boiler models, manufacturers,index numbers, etc.?

Comment: @Nefarii, it seems more likely that they are tokens to be replaced with column values from some data row.  They don't appear to be start and end markers.

Comment: Yeah Im guessing they are going to be replaced with column values. How Im reading the question though is that he is being presented with the complete/finished string and he needs to get the individual items out of the string. So there might be a 1000 different strings with different manufacturers, boilers, and he needs to know the details of each string without knowing what is going to be there. I was just hoping for a little clarification.

Comment: @Nefarii Yes.  Same here.  But clarification which unfortunately does not appear to be forthcoming...

Comment: @RNar attempt is obvious with a regex and i am not good at it so did not posted my try but i should have.

Comment: @Nefarri yes I will replace the col_x value with a certain value from data  to complete the string as an English sentance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
string[] result = Regex.Matches(input, @"\[(col_\d+)\]").
                            Cast<Match>().
                            Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).
                            ToArray();
```

Comment: I think he is trying to find the actual values of [col 5], [col 6], etc - which will be different in every string .

Comment: @Nefarii If so, the OP ought to fix his example desired outcome in the question.

Comment: Good idea. This can be written shorter using this regex [`(?<=\[)[^\]]+`](http://goo.gl/Ed2dx4). Having this only interesting chars will match and your Linq will be `.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()`.

Comment: This is final answer. `Regex.Matches(input, @"\[(col_\d+)\]").
                            Cast<Match>().
                            Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).
                            ToArray();`

Comment: @Verarind good point.  Taking the group out of it does simplify the reading of the results in the c# code.  You could keep the restrictiveness without using the group if both a look-behind and a look-ahead were used: `(?<=\[)col_\d+(?=\])`.

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch I updated my answer to reflect that.  I was initially going to use `\d` and then I switched to `[0-9]` because for some reason I had the mistaken impression that `\d` allowed dots and commas.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's what you need:

```
  string pattern = @"\[(col_\d+)\]";
  MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
  string[] results = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

Replace input with your input string.

I hope it helps

Comment: yes but he corrected the 0-9 limit with generic regex so one vote.

Comment: @ahmadalibaloch Maybe. I added a comment in doggarts answer. There is a shorter way possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hacky but you could do this.

```
var myMessage =@"[col_5] is a central heating boiler..."; //etc.

var values = Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
             .Select(x => "[col_" + x + "]")
             .Where(x => myMessage.Contains(x))
             .ToList();
```

Assuming there is a known max col_"x" in this case I assumed 100, it just tries them all by brute force returning only the ones that it finds inside the text.

If you know that there are only so many columns to hunt for, I would try this instead of Regex personally as I have had too many bad experiences burning hours on Regex.

Comment: Good.. its easy really and new information. Thanks.